# Where does MS-Windows store the position of windows closed with Shift+[X]?

Tags: windows

Obviously, each application might store its window size/position in its own way, as covered by [this question in 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/532256/where-is-the-information-about-the-position-of-a-window-stored?noredirect=1&lq=1).  There's no uniform location on disk or in the registry and everybody does their own thing.  Some isolated programs store windowing information under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE` but it's the wild wild west as to how they do it.

But capital-W Windows also has (or had, depending on which flavor of Windows you bought) a feature in which you can close a program by Shift-clicking the big "[X]" in the window titlebar, and the windows' size and position will be stored for the next invocation.

Is *that* feature standardized?  Because if it is, then that size/position information would have to be stored somewhere, and ideally in a standardized location, if the same Shift+[X] code is handling it all.  Does anybody know where the Shift+[X] information is stored?

(I'm really hoping that the Shift+[X] action doesn't merely call an application's own "hey, you should consider storing your windowing information somewhere, but it's up to you how to do that" function, because then we're back to the first paragraph of every software doing its own thing.)